# On start debugging a new browser window pops up in flutter using vscode

Tags: flutter, web

I'm trying to hot reload my flutter app that runs on a browser but whenever i run  `ctrl + f5` or `f5` a new blank browser window appears.

Can someone help please

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try `flutter run -d chrome`   to Run Chrome using the default renderer option

Comment: With that command  the app will run , but i don't wan't to rerun it everytime i make a change and thats where hot reload comes in(which does not work when i ctrl + f5)